# Is it possible to copy files from amazon aws s3 directly to remote server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, server

I receive some large data to process and I would like to copy the files to my remote GPU server for processing.

the data contains 8000 files x 9GB/per file which is quite large.

Is it possible to copy the files from aws directly to the remote server (used with ssh)

I have googled it online and did not find anyone come up with the question..

If anyone could kindly provide a guide/url example I would appreciate a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have SSH access to the "remote server," then make an SSH connection to it.  Now, it is no longer the "remote" server -- it is now the "local" server because you are logged into it and you are sitting at its command prompt.  Now, your question is different: "how do I download files to *this* server, from S3?"  And the answer should be more apparent.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your files are residing in S3.

If that is the case then you can simply install AWS CLI on your remote machine and use `aws s3 cp` command

For more details [click here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)